# Program rolls dice number of times(Using arrays), and must display the number of times a number rolled (Except it doesn't work))

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The goal of my program is to roll a two six sided dices then add the two, (1000 times) and print out how many times the number '4' rolled in the program. I have tried using the math.random class outside and inside of the loop with making no clear difference, and even not using a for loop to begin with, my goal is to eventually call the output to the main method in order to print it. The count4++ I heard would work for such operation except some error is causing me to work against it. Any help, guidance or advise would be much appreciated. I do apologize for not having the best code writing format, skills, or general knowledge, please  be aware that this is my first year taking programming. 
I receive the error  count4++; cannot be resolved, and the only way to fix it is to set it to 0 which ruins my program because it always prints 0.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Delt {


public static void main (String args [] ) throws IOException {

int i; 
int Sixside1;
int Sixside2;
int count4 = 0;
int [] data = new int [1000];
input (data);

System.out.println("The number of times '4' came up in the six sided dices is :" + count4);




}
public static void input (int num []) throws IOException {
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
String input;

System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
System.out.println("In this program two six sided dices will be rolled and one eleven sided dice will be rolled (1000 times each");

System.out.println("The dices will be rolled to determine the odds of how many times the roll 4 comes up on both dies(Press any key to con't) ");
input = myInput.readLine ();



for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
{
  int Sixside1 = (int) (Math.random ()*(6-4) + 4); 
  int Sixside2 = (int) (Math.random ()*(6-4) + 4); 

  double total = Sixside1 + Sixside2;
  if ( total == 4) {
    // print amount of times 4 shows up in 1000 rolls, ?? 
    count4++;
    //return it to main method??
  }
}
} }
```

Comment: Could you define "some error" please - with a stack trace and where the error happens.

Comment: I receive the error  count4++; cannot be resolved, and the only way to fix it is to set it to 0 which ruins my program because it always prints 0

Comment: You need to declare `count4` as a variable in your `input` method.

Comment: simply declaring it will ask me to initialize it, once initialized to 0, it always prints 0

Comment: I can't see how your total will ever be anything less the 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing the local variable `count4` - which has to be done. Before the loop you can have: `int count4 = 0;`. A local variable in one method is different from a local variable in another method, so what I suggest is that you return the `count4` variable from the `input()` method to the main method, and print that out.

You're also not calculating the die-rolls as you're suppose to, meaning you'll never get a sum of 4. `Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1 (exclusive) - so your dies will be: (int) (0-0.999)*2+4=(int)(0-1.999)+4=(int)4-5.9999= 4-5. Instead, use `(int)Math.random()*6+1`.

Edit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    System.out.println(input());
}

public static int input () throws IOException {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
    System.out.println("In this program two six sided dices will be rolled and one eleven sided dice will be rolled (1000 times each");

    System.out.println("The dices will be rolled to determine the odds of how many times the roll 4 comes up on both dies(Press any key to con't) ");
    myInput.readLine();
    int count4=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    {
        if ( (int)(Math.random ()*6+1)+(int)(Math.random ()*6+1) == 4) {
            count4++;
        }
    }
    return count4;
}
```

Comment: As i stated before, initializing count4 to 0, prints out zero each time i run the program! (I just tried both your suggestions)

Comment: As I said in my answer, it has to do with two reasons: One, you never get 4 because of the error in your die-rolls. Two, because you're never printing the actual variable.

Comment: But I am printing the variable in the main method, do you suggest, i print it again in the custom method?

Comment: @user2184171 They're different variables. To return a variable from the method, replace void with int - and at the end of the method add a line `return count4;` - that way the method will be returning the int to the main method.

Comment: I still get it to print 0, each time the program runs.

Comment: Sorry to bother you though, I can see that this seems to be a near unsolvable question.

Comment: Did you change the die-rolls? Also, in the main method you have to save and print what you get from the input() method, as such: int count4 = input(data);

Comment: It still prints out 0 mate, even with that changed, and the die-rolls.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong in your end then.. See my edit: it's a minimal version that works fine here.

Comment: do I still place count4 = input(data) in the main method, and initialize the arrays strings and integers, because the count4 in main is giving me my one and only error right now.

Comment: "the method input () in the type ... is not applicable"

Comment: Try `System.out.println(input()+"");` instead, my IDE figures that out for me.

Comment: Hold on, i just tried your exact copy of the edit, and it worked, except I'm confused, on why it did, without the things in the main method. Nonetheless I am thankful for the effort you have put together sir, and appreciate every comment you have made, and possibly could make. This website has certainly helped me with assignments when i have been stuck completely. Your a great example of a person who does not mind helping someone out, despite any given circumstances. Again, thank you!

Comment: Just a last input though, what if I wanted two dices in the same range, and wanted to add their rolls together, could i just do another && comment in the if statement>?